# .NET ResourceManager.GetResourceSet: "en-GB" not working on english resource

Tags: .net, localization

Is there a way in .NET to make the following calls:

```
ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(new CultureInfo("en-GB"), true, false)
 ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(new CultureInfo("en-US"), true, false)
```

work also for non british (only "en") resources like:

```
Resources.en.resx
```

With no "en-GB.resx/en-US.resx" - file defined above calls will always return null. I would like them to fallback to the default en.resx if no more specific file (like en-GB.resx or en-US.resx) is found.

NOTE: Setting the third parameter of GetResourceSet (tryParaments) to true will just return the default non tagged Resources.resx file, even though en is set in the CultureInfos parent property..

Comment: That should be standard behavior. Are you sure everything is setup correctly? Can you access the "en" resource directly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get all keys from the invariant culture and then you can lookup all translation. So the fallback works.

```
var keys = Resources.ResourceManager
    .GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, true, true)
    .Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
    .Select(entry => entry.Key)
    .Cast<string>();

var enUsResources = keys.ToDictionary(
    key => key, 
    key => Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(key, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")));
```